# Is there a way that while running pygame, I can also run the console too?

Tags: python, pygame, livewires

I was wondering if there is a way, in python, that while my graphical piece inside my games.screen.mainloop() is running, if I can do something like get user input through raw_input() from the console.

Comment: do you mean without stopping the loop?

Comment: If you're using Linux, run the command with an ampersand (&) at the end of the line

Comment: yeah, without stopping the games.screen.mainloop()

Answer (score 6):

Yes, have a look at the following example:

```
import pygame
import threading
import queue

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
quit_game = False

commands = queue.Queue()

pos = pygame.Vector2(10, 10)

m = {'w': (0, -10),
     'a': (-10, 0),
     's': (0, 10),
     'd': (10, 0)}

class Input(threading.Thread):
  def run(self):
    while not quit_game:
      command = input()
      commands.put(command)

i = Input()
i.start()

old_pos = []

while not quit_game:
  try:
    command = commands.get(False)
  except queue.Empty:
    command = None

  if command in m:
    old_pos.append((int(pos.x), int(pos.y)))
    pos += m[command]

  for e in pygame.event.get():
    if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
      print("press enter to exit")
      quit_game = True

  screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
  for p in old_pos:
      pygame.draw.circle(screen, (75, 0, 0), p, 10, 2)
  pygame.draw.circle(screen, (200, 0, 0), (int(pos.x), int(pos.y)), 10, 2)
  pygame.display.flip()

i.join()
```

It creates a little red circle. You can move it around with entering <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>d</kbd> into the console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The thing is about that is if you do something like `raw_input` it will stop the program until that input is entered so that will stop the program every loop to take input but you can do things like `print` but they will print every loop

if you want to take input use [InputBox Module](http://www.pygame.org/pcr/inputbox/) this will make a little input box pop up on the screen thats in the loop

if you want to do it from the console you could try Threading it which im not to familiar with but you can check it out [Multi-threading Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)

here is a questions that might help you out

[Pygame writing to terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183401/pygame-write-to-other-terminal)

Good Luck! :)